# How to concatenate text variables in python

Tags: python, file, text, concatenation

I have a real beginner question. I would like to do the following:

```
FileName1 = open(r'C:\Users\data.txt')
PointID = '1'
```

Now, I'd like to create a new variable that is set to be equal to File1, i.e. a concatenation of File and PointID, or something like this if the variables were both strings:

```
FieldFile = FileName + PointID
```

Could anyone suggest a way to combine these into one variable called FieldFile?

Much Appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to achieve? Do you just want to add `1` to the end of the filename you're passing to `open`, or...?

Comment: I should have written the code to look like it does now (I edited it). I am trying to pass the contents of "FileName1" to a new variable called FieldFile. I need it to depend on the PointID because I will have FileName1, FileName2, FileName3... and so on. If I use suggestions from @OrangeFlash81 I get what I asked for, which is a string, but what I want is the contents of my original file not as a string.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `open`, the result isn't a string. To read the contents of the file as a string, call `.read` on the result of your `open` call:

```
File = open(r'C:\Users\data.txt').read()
PointID = '1'
```

You can now concatenate your two string variables like you've suggested:

```
FieldFile = File + PointID
```